# Intellij does not start after linux update

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Kubuntu with intellij.

What can i do to fix the error.

I get the folowing error:

```
2013-07-28 21:57:56,874 [   3947]  ERROR - nSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl - Original exception:  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/openapi/util/IconLoader.getIcon must not return null
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getIcon(IconLoader.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getIcon(IconLoader.java:78)
    at org.intellij.lang.xpath.xslt.associations.impl.AssociationsGroup.<init>(AssociationsGroup.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.b(ActionManagerImpl.java:474)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:863)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.a(ActionManagerImpl.java:206)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.<init>(ActionManagerImpl.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:665)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:616)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:218)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:194)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:477)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionManager.getInstance(ActionManager.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeMouseEventDispatcher.a(IdeMouseEventDispatcher.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeMouseEventDispatcher.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeMouseEventDispatcher.java:166)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:510)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.b(IdeEventQueue.java:411)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:369)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(JOptionPane.java:870)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:667)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:638)
    at javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.java:609)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.handleInitComponentError(ApplicationImpl.java:332)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:700)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:616)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:218)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:665)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:616)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:218)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.DecoratingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(DecoratingComponentAdapter.java:60)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.CachingComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:665)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:616)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:218)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.a(ComponentManagerImpl.java:147)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.a(ComponentManagerImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.initComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:389)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:101)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$3.run(MainImpl.java:156)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:662)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:515)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.b(IdeEventQueue.java:411)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:369)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: it seems you may have deleted some intellij files by accident, reinstall it

Comment: Tried it but with no success. The newes version works (Trial) but my 10.5 does not. Which folders do i have to delete to make a fresh reinstall of intellij?

Comment: I don't in linux how it is, but In Windows just uninstall util. You may find from google how to uninstall on linux,then install it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are using an older Version of PHPStorm with a newer JVM (>= 1.7.0_25). Depending on your system setup, you can try to launch PHPStorm with an older Version of Java, like Java 6.

I had the same problem and solved it starting it with

```
 WEBIDE_JDK=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/ /opt/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

You can also try to move the plugins xpath and xslt_debugger to another location if you don't need them.

In Ubuntu you can set the default Java VM with the command

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

Which version of PHPStorm and which JVM are you actually using?